# C++ Calling Functions with Parameters from Map

Tags: c++

I am playing around with some code that I previously used to call void functions that were parameter-less from a map. However, I can't seem figure out how to pass arguments to the functions I store in a map.

This code should display a menu such as:

```
1. Edit Record
2. Delete Record
3. Select Another Record
q. Quit
```

When you select 1,2,3, or "q" the corresponding action in the map should execute.

Here is the code so far:

```
void DisplaySelectedRecordOptions(Record &rec)
{
    struct SelectedRecordOptions
    {
        string option;
        function<void()> action;
    };

    static const map <string, SelectedRecordOptions> SelectedRecordOptionsTable
    {
        { "1",{ "Edit Record", []() { EditRecord(rec); } } },
        { "2",{ "Delete Record", []() { cout << "WORK IN PROGRESS\n"; } } },
        { "3",{ "Select Another Record", []() { cout << "WORK IN PROGRESS\n"; } } },
        { "q",{ "Quit", []() { cout << "Quit" << "\n";  } } }
    };

    for (auto const& x : SelectedRecordOptionsTable)
    {
        cout << x.first << ". " << (x.second).option << "\n";
    }

    string input;

    while (SelectedRecordOptionsTable.count(input) == 0)
    {
        input = GetInput();
    }

    SelectedRecordOptionsTable.at(input).action();
}
```

I get the following error trying to run:

```
an enclosing-function local variable cannot be referenced in a lambda body unless it is in the capture list
```

Here is the EditRecord function that I am wanting to try to implement within the map:

```
void EditRecord(Record &rec)
{
    string description;
    string username;
    string password;

    cout << "Description: ";
    getline(cin, description);
    cout << "Username: ";
    getline(cin, username);
    cout << "Password: ";
    getline(cin, password);

    rec.description = description;
    rec.userName = username;
    rec.password = password;
}
```

Comment: What's not clear about the error message? You need to capture the variable in your lambda. `[&]() { EditRecord(rec); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make your lambda capture the used variables. Simple way is like this

```
[&]() { EditRecord(rec); }
```

The `&` causes your lambda to capture all variables *by reference*. There are alternatives which is why this doesn't happen by default. You can [research these for yourself](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: This won't work.  `rec` is an argument to the function, but the map is `static`.

Comment: @MartinBonner Hmm, missed that. Some redesign needed.

Comment: @okkv1747vm I'd be cautious, Your map is only populated once, but the function is presumably called multiple times, so this seems like undefined behaviour to me.

Comment: The simple redesign is "make the map non-static".  The complex one is "make all the actions take `rec` as an argument, and pass it in".  At the same time, could you make that `while` loop into a `do-while` loop which sets an iterator, so that invoking the action doesn't need to do another look-up ... oh, and the map should be an unordered map.

Comment: @john I don't understand how that could be a problem if the map isn't changing. Do you mind elaborating on your concerns?

Comment: @okkv1747vm When the map is initialised a lambda is created which holds a reference to `rec`. Effectively the first time that `DisplaySelectedRecordOptions` is called the address of `rec` is saved in your map. The next time `DisplaySelectedRecordOptions` is called the address of `rec` might be different and so you'd be using an invalid address. Now in practise I imagine you are always calling `DisplaySelectedRecordOptions` from the same place in your code with the same call stack. So the address is always the same and you don't notice any problem.

Comment: But it's still undefined behaviour because you are saving a reference to an object and then using it beyond the lifetime of that object.

Comment: @MartinBonner Would making the map non-static alleviate the "undefined behavior?" Curious, why should the map be an unordered map?

Comment: @okkv1747vm Making the map non-static means it would be reinitialized every time the function is called, so the captured reference to `rec` would not outlast the lifetime of `rec`.  It should be an unordered map because there is no advantage to making it ordered, and in general one should prefer unordered (which has O(1) lookup rather tan O(log n).)